# IIS Media Service using BLOB Storage

Tags: iis, azure, windows-media-services

since BLOB storage does not yet support smooth streaming, and since SMarx's application has some limitations and may possibly break with future streaming protocol changes, I would like to host IIS Media Services in a Virtual Machine role and pull the video bits from blob storage. My idea as of this second revolves around having the VM instance contain a web site whose contents is output from Expression 4. The contents of the website directory is provided (kept in sync) with new blob entries/deletes using something like CloudBerry. Is this a complete and utter kludge?

Answer (score 0):

One thought that comes to mind is - why VM Role?  I recently wrote a blog post about installing Windows Features into a worker role - the same ideas would apply to installing media services into a web role + IIS.  Otherwise, I see no reason why this would not work.  Obviously the admonition to always run at least 2 instances applies...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/golive/archive/2011/08/15/installing-windows-features-in-a-windows-azure-role-instance.aspx